# Why vendor dir is misplaced after composer update?

Tags: dependencies, composer

I've [VM](https://github.com/mycognitive/drupal-sandbox/tree/371b65b55e3cb2f11c6aff834b3069785b7bb12a) with the following `composer.json` file in `/vagrant`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

then when I run `composer update` in that folder, it's downloading the requirements but to `/vagrant/vendor`, instead of [expected](http://akrabat.com/global-installation-of-php-tools-with-composer/) local HOME directory as usual (`~/.composer/vendor`).

Is there any reason why and how to fix that?

I'm using:

```
Composer version 1.0-dev (15face5432d7b7334db6ac69fac0190971cafa6e) 2015-09-23 17:46:25
```

on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how composer works.  If you want something added to `~/.composer/vendor`, then you should put it in `~/.composer/composer.json`.  By default, the vendor directory will be placed next to the `composer.json` file.

You have a couple of options here.  The best is probably to just dispense with `/vendor/composer.json`, and just run `composer global require "drush/drush": "dev-master"` instead.  That will add `drush/drush` to `~/.composer/composer.json`, and install it.  You will then have a symlink to the Drush directory in `~/.composer/vendor/bin`, which is, I suspect, what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

As for workaround, to use JSON file which is not in `~/.composer/composer.json`, [vendor path can be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11883374/55075) in `config`/`vendor-dir`, for example:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "~/.composer/vendor"
    },
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

which should install `drush` in `~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush`, then appropriate change to PATH variable needs to be done, e.g.

```
ex +'$s@$@\rexport PATH=\~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH@' -cwq ~/.bashrc
```

---

To make it global (by running as `root`), I guess `/var/lib/vendor` can be used for `vendor-dir`, and either append the proper path to PATH variable in one of the global files such as `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`, alternatively specify [`bin-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md) in JSON file, for example:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/var/lib/vendor",
        "bin-dir": "/usr/local/bin"
    },
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

which will install `drush` globally with a minimal headache as `/usr/local/bin` should be already in the PATH.

---

Or if you don't want to hardcode the path in JSON file (so it can be shared between different services), there is even much simpler way as suggested by [jonhattan](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1628#issuecomment-143177058), for example:

- VM way (as root):

  ```
  COMPOSER_HOME=/var/lib/composer COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=/var/lib/composer/vendor composer -nqq install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader
  ```
- Travis CI way:

  ```
  COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=~/bin composer -nqq install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --prefer-source
  ```

Instead of `install`, you can also use `update`.